# How can I match bangladeshi phone number using RegExp in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

this following expression is working for any 11 digits phone number. But I want the first three digit to be specific operator code like (017, 016, 018, 019). And rest of the others can be any digits.

```
/^([\d]{3})*([\d]{8})$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use an alternation here:

```
/^(01[6789])(\d{8})$/
```

Code sample:

```js
console.log(/^(01[6789])(\d{8})$/.test('01612345678')); // pass
console.log(/^(01[6789])(\d{8})$/.test('01912345678')); // pass
console.log(/^(01[6789])(\d{8})$/.test('12312345678')); // fail
```